# Corona SDK - event "touch", phase "moved" - detect if currently over an object

Tags: lua, hover, touch, coronasdk

For example I have a couple of static circles (or some other objects) drawn, and called

```
circle:addEventListener("touch", onTouch)
```

for all of them.

Inside function onTouch is there a simple way to find out if the new touching coordinates are over another object?

```
local function onTouch(event)
    local c = event.target
    local phase = event.phase
    if (phase == "moved") then
        -- HERE
        -- I would like to receive a pointer to the object I'm hovering over
    end
    return true  -- Prevents touch propagation to underlying objects
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save references to display objects in table `circles`. Next, inside `onTouch` function in `moved` phase iterate over items in table `circles` to find objects you hovering over. You can use property [`object.contentBounds`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/contentBounds.html) to find boundaries of an object, in content coordinates.

Comment: Thank you, object.contentBounds simplifies my current implementation a lot!
If noone replies "here is a Corona SDK function that checks is the coordinates are inside the DisplayObject" soon, this will be the answer.